# First order nonlinear differential equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, first-order-logic

The question asks to find y given y(x) is a differentiable function satisfying:

$\frac{dy}{dx}$=-$2xy^4$ , $y(0)$=$\frac{1}{3}$ and $y(x)>0$ , and explain why it is unique.

I assume the steps are to integrate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to get a function for y(x), then use $y(0)=1/3$ to find the constant and then set $y(x)>0$ to find y but i keep getting stuck.

A differential equation solution gives $y(x)$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{c_1+3x^2}}$ , which I can use $y(0)$ to find $c_1$ but then I'm not sure how to get y from that since the equation doesn't have any y's in it.

A similar question I found on this site showed to rearrange and integrate each side like $\int$$\frac{dy}{y^4}$=$\int$$-2xdx$ which gives $-\frac{1}{3y^3}+c_1$=$-x^2+c_2$ , but then I don't know how to get $y(x)$ from that frunction, it seems further from the solution than my first try.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a simple manipulation:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\frac{1}{3y^3}+c_1=-x^2+c_2
 & \iff -\frac{1}{3y^3} = -x^2 + c_2-c_1 \\
 & \iff \frac{1}{3y^3} = x^2 +c_1-c_2 \\
 & \iff y^3 = \frac{1}{3x^2 + 3(c_1-c_2)} \\
 & \iff y = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3x^2+3(c_1-c_2)}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now it's just note that $3(c_1-c_2)$ is constant, say $k$, and we obtain
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3x^2+k}}.$$

Comment: Is that all I need as the complete answer? No need to use the given properties/conditions?

Comment: The given differential equation is separable, and the method to solve separable first order differential equations is as you've mentioned in your question. What I have done is manipulate your partial solution to get the solution you said don't know how to get it. Am I missing something?

Comment: What did you mean by "(...) set $y(x) > 0$ to find $y$ (...)" ? As I see it, $y$ is just a function, not an incognite.

Comment: Judging by the conditions the question gave I assumed I would end up with an equation y(x) in terms of y and x with a constant that I would need to compute using y(0)=1/3, and then set that equation <0 to get y<some function of x.

Comment: I'm thinking that y(x) and y are two different things, are they not?

Comment: The question asks you to find a function $y$ satisfying $y' = -2xy^4$, $y(0) = 1/3$ and $y(x) > 0$ for all $x$. Note that $y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3x^2+27}}$ satisfies these conditions.

Comment: They're the same thing as well

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, I didn't even recognise that your manipulation of my second attempt actually ended up as the same answer to my first attempt. Thank you!

Comment: Nice. Any time !